# Burn a season of AVI's to a non-DivX DVD player

Tags: video, conversion, dvd, avi, burning

I know this is a noob question,

but I downloaded a season of my favorite show since all the DVD's mysteriously went missing. I want to burn them to blank DVD's but I'm not sure how I can do that in a way that my DVD player will use it.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DVDFlick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) is free, supports a bunch of codecs/containers, and uses ImgBurn to write the disc image. The settings are a bit confusing but there are helpful tooltips right next to most of them.

I've used this program to burn ancient DivX files, Theora/Vorbis videos, movies in Matroska containers, etc. all to standard video DVDs without problems. It takes a while though, depending on your machine's specs, it takes a good 2 hours to burn a 2hr movie on my 3.4GHz Pentium D machine.

Comment: I adore DVDFlick. I've been looking for an application like it for YEARS!

Comment: @skelly Is this an app that allows me to use .avi files on my crappy dvd player?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [ConvertXToDVD](http://www.vso-software.fr/products/convert_x_to_dvd/)?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows I use [TheFilmMachine](http://members.home.nl/thefilmmachine/) to convert full-length videos to DVD format ready for burning.

It strings everything into one movie though, so for episodic content you need to use the "just create files for authoring" option then use the resulting files with something that can make a DVD menu and arrange a disk accordingly (unless you are happy with the episodes being strung together like that).