# Ensure a burned DVD will work any dvd player?

Tags: burning

My bro used to burn DVD's with some special format to ensure that they would even work on crummy, cheap, old DVD players.  Well, I'm using one of 'those' dvd players.  So, I want to be sure that I format my burned dvd's properly.  What can I do to be sure that my dvd's play properly?

As I recall, we could even use CD disks to on old DVD players, and the CD's would be loaded with .avi files.  I believe the format started with an s and had an h in it.

Comment: Also, this may be a duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/22941/burn-a-season-of-avis-to-a-non-divx-dvd-player

Comment: Ask your bro what he used? :/

Comment: Different time zones.  It's like 3 a.m. where he is.

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of svcd's.

This might help:
http://www.deskshare.com/resources/articles/video-dvd-formats.aspx