# Burn movies to CD's that will play on a standard DVD?

Tags: dvd, burning, cd-burning

Is this possible?  My memory is a little foggy, but I believe I've done this in the past.

I'm not sure if it can be done with all dvd players.  How can it be done?

Comment: Define "standard DVD".

Comment: Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers). You already posted a very similar [question](http://superuser.com/questions/836126/ensure-a-burned-dvd-will-work-any-dvd-player) which is getting answers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup vcd's.  I did it a long time ago, I'm assuming it's still relevant.

Comment: What I'm looking at is: after converting to VCD, how do I burn to a CD?  Just copy the data and click 'burn', or do I need to format the disc in some special way using some special software?

Comment: That I can't remember =/  Probably some good youtube vids for it out there.  I seem to recall just writing a normal data cd with nero but I really don't remember for sure.

Comment: You can't store VCD on a hard drive, it exists only on CDs. It's created during burning. There is no such thing as converting to VCD. Please do some research before asking questions.

Comment: That's cool and everything, but I've gone through about 20 CD's trying to figure out how to actually get SVCD's onto CD's. :/